# What does "shot" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

> Another shot before we kiss the other
>   side.

This is from Lady Gaga's recent song, "Edge of Glory."

A subtitled video can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hKv4BaDl7o). This is probably better than just reading the lyrics.

Comment: Song lyrics are notoriously difficult to decipher, since they carry a lot of poetic encoding.  One line isn't much context; you'll need to give us more if you want anything other than guesses.

Comment: Ok, I added a link to the whole song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised no one is really sure what "shot" is. It's a glass of [alcolholic drink:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shot)

> informal  a glass of alcoholic drink, esp spirits

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shot) expands:

> A measure of alcohol, usually spirits, as taken either from a shot-glass or directly from the bottle, equivalent to about 44 milliliters; 1.5 ounces. ("pony shot"= 30 milliliters; 1 fluid ounce)

It just refers to "let's have another drink before we kiss the other side". Simple.

Just an extra, in "kiss the other side", "the other side" refers to death, or the end. The other side, as in the afterlife.

All in all, it's "Let's have another alcoholic drink before we go to the other side."

Answer (score 4):

My guess is another alcoholic drink. A shot is a term for a strong alcoholic drink like vodka or rum served in a small glass.

[Wikipedia article on the shot glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_glass)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know the song but 'shot' can either mean a try or attempt, as in "give it a shot".

Or it can mean a single drink of liquor, as in "a shot of whisky"